# Strong parameters only for update/create or for all actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

The nested format that [strong parameters](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) requires comes automatically with forms, i.e. the `update` and `create` actions.

Does this mean that it's only meant for those actions, and for the other get requests we're supposed to use plain old `params[:token]` in the controller?

The reason why I'm asking is to understand whether I should create the nested format aswell for get requests like this `link_to user.first_name, user_path(user: {token: user.token})` or simply do `link_to user.first_name, user_path(token: user.token)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strong params is a security mechanism having to do only with actions that add or change data, specifically actions that do this for several attributes at the same time, hence the name mass assignment. Usually the typical controller methods that use mass assignment are Create and Update, therefore these are usually the only methods one would have to protect. I say usually because you can always have a custom controller method that uses mass assignment.

Mass assignment looks like this:

```
attrs = {:first => "John", :last => "Doe", :email => "john.doe@example.com"}
user = User.new(attrs)
```

You now have a user with all those attributes assigned to it, it's a convenience thing. Otherwise you would have to do each attribute manually. The problem is if you don't whitelist the attributes that can be assigned via strong params, someone could manipulate the POST or PUT/PATCH request to say something like this `:admin => true`

Hope that makes it a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0):

[Strong Parameters](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) provide an interface for protecting attributes from end-user ***assignment***. With [Strong Parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) Action Controller parameters are forbidden to be used in Active Model ***mass assignments*** until they have been whitelisted. This means you'll have to make a conscious choice about which attributes to allow for ***mass updating*** and thus prevent accidentally exposing that which shouldn't be exposed.

So, this is applicable for `create` and `update` actions as you are updating the attributes in these two type of actions. In a `GET` request, you are not updating any attributes. So, strong parameter does not require in those requests.

Answer (score 0):

In Short, we need to verify and update with strong parameters for all `POST` & `PATCH`(`PUT`) Method actions.